# including python in c++ setup

Tags: python, c++, cpython

I am trying to embed python into my c++ program. I have included the libs and the python Include directory in to the project's properties. But when I try to run the c++ program I receive the error:
`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)`

and also:

```
 fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

note: I am using windows and visual studio.

Comment: You're missing the `WinMain` function - which likely means you either misconfigured your project (window vs console application), or did not provide an appropriate main function

Comment: Thank you. My project Linker>SubSystem is set to WINDOWS but I am still getting the same error. Do I know have to change the main function? and what do I change it to?

Comment: [WinMain entry point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks I got it all working.